# iOS Downloading image in background and updating the UI

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nstimer, nsrunloop

I am trying update an imageview with new image for every 1 sec by downloading the image from the server. The downloading happens in background thread. Below shown is the code

```
 NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.5
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                       userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];



-(void)timerFired:(id)sender
 {
    NSURLRequest *request=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL      


    URLWithString:@"http://192.168.4.116:8080/RMC/ImageWithCommentData.jpg"]];

    NSOperationQueue *queueTmp = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queueTmp completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
   {
     if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
     {

         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(processImageData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:TRUE modes:nil];

     }

     else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
     {

     }
     else if (error != nil)
     {



     }

 }];
}


-(void)processImageData:(NSData*)imageData
{
  NSLog(@"data downloaded");
  [self.hmiImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
 }
```

My image is getting downloaded. But ProcessImageData method is not called. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: why you need to update view on every second ? I don't know your requirement, but it don't looks healthy.

Comment: Did you check the length of downloaded `data` whether it is 0 or not.

Comment: But your requirement looks confusing, don't know why you want to download the image for every sec.

Comment: Thats not a problem whether he is downloading 1 sec or every ms it is going to be background . and it will no more affects UI.

Comment: try with replacing  queueTmp with  [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]

Comment: Or just write directly  if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
     { [self.hmiImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];}

Comment: By replacing performSelectoronmainthread with  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                
                 [self processImageData:data];
                 
             }); fixed the issue. I am not sure why using perform selector main thread dosent work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are calling NSURLConnection asynchronously :

```
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queueTmp completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
```

so before you get any data the  :  `if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)` get called . 
so the  data length remains 0 thats why your method is not called . for achieving your requirement you can do like :

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {

            NSData *imageData = //download image here 
            UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
            if (image) {
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        //set image here
                     }
                 });
             }
        });
```

Comment: This isn't correct. The completion handler is called after the data is retrieved.